# What is the correct way to deal with RestKit Request when the View Controller is being popped?

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I have a HTTP request in Navigation Controller by:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:url delegate:self];
```

But if user presses the back button when the request is still running, the app crashed:

```
*** -[UITableView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xeab5600
```

I added the following code in viewWillUnload (and viewDidUnload) to cancel the request, but got the same error:

```
[[RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue cancelRequestsWithDelegate:self];
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when the view is being popped from navigation controller, viewDidUnload and viewWillUnload did not be triggered. So I moved the cancelRequestsWithDelegate method to viewWillDisappear to solve the problem.